# Method not allowed error getting this result when i heroku logs on CLI

Tags: node.js, heroku

[image: heroku logs]

What is that status code for favicon.ico i have not used that link to my website but i know that could be used to insert a favicon icon in my page title.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured that when I put `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));` below `app.use({express.static("public")});` it works else it was giving error 405 method not allowed.